# Android contacts High-Res DisplayPhoto not showing up

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm saving high-resolution display photo into Android Contacts using a method from dev guide: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto

Just after save Contacts table looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| *** Contacts table ***                                                                                                                                         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| _id | raw_contact_id | display_name | photo_id | file_id |                  photo_thumb_uri                  |                    photo_uri                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 661 |    661         | ContactName  |   6125   |    26   | content://com.android.contacts/contacts/661/photo | content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/26 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PhotoUri is correct and indeed I can load High-Res Photo using that URI.

But then, after a few moments, Contact Synchronization Service is started:

```
2019-08-30 15:17:42.991 14029-19208/? W/FSA2_ContactsSyncAdapter: @onPerformSync Sync started
2019-08-30 15:17:43.056 14029-19208/? W/ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context
2019-08-30 15:17:43.056 14029-19208/? W/ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context

2019-08-30 15:17:43.721 14029-19208/? I/FSA2_SyncState: @readSyncState: # aohd@ea156530

2019-08-30 15:17:44.133 14029-19208/? I/FSA2_SyncState: @readSyncState: # aohd@4c3cbbea

2019-08-30 15:17:44.335 14029-19208/? E/PhotoUrlUtil: Photo cell is empty.

2019-08-30 15:17:45.242 14029-19208/? I/FSA2_SyncUpPhotoCursor: Start to upload photo for contact 74ae94138cec7df6
2019-08-30 15:17:45.248 14029-19208/? E/PhotoUrlUtil: Photo cell is empty.
2019-08-30 15:17:45.248 14029-19208/? E/PhotoUrlUtil: Photo cell is empty.

2019-08-30 15:17:47.016 14029-19208/? W/FSA2_ContactsSyncAdapter: @onPerformSync Sync finished successfully
```

After synchronization Contacts table is incorrect, and there is no reference to high res photo, but only to thumbnail (low-res) photo.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| *** Contacts table ***                                                                                                                                           |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| _id | raw_contact_id | display_name | photo_id | file_id |                  photo_thumb_uri                  |                    photo_uri                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 661 |    661         | ContactName  |   6125   |   null  | content://com.android.contacts/contacts/661/photo | content://com.android.contacts/contacts/661/photo |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can no more read high-res data using URI from the contacts table. I am using for reading the following method:

```
//true is for high-res photos
ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, contactUri, true)
```

At the same time, the "Google Contacts" application is able to load the high-res contact photo. When I start Google contacts application high-res photo appears after a short while in the contact details view. After opening contact in Google app I can see again correct entries in Contact tables.

As I understand showing Contact in Google app is realized in QuickContactActivity:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/contacts/quickcontact/QuickContactActivity.java#1120

I would like to understand what is the correct way of saving (or loading) contact's high-res photo. It is enough for me to get a high-level description. I have investigated Google Contacts app source code, but I can not find any simple clue how it is done by them. Providing a simple, algorithmic recipe based on Google app is also counted as a solution.

I am testing application on Android Emulator, API level 28, min. level 21.

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I can observe the same process (as described above) while saving a contact photo using Google Contact application. So it seems that resolving high-res photo information is done during a photo read - it's not a problem with saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have finally found the correct solution. Basically, before viewing a high-resolution photo, you should trigger the synchronization of a contact's photo in sync adapter service. When the synchronization is finished, you are able to retrieve the high-resolution photo and you can set it on your UI. Before synchronization, commonly, you will be able to use only thumbnail quality photos.

Now the function which dispatches intent to start high-resolution photo synchronization (Kotlin):

```
fun dispatchSyncHighResPhotoIntent(context: Context, rawContactId: Long) {
    val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId)
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    intent.component = ComponentName(
        "com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts",
        "com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts.SyncHighResPhotoIntentService"
    )
    intent.action = "com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts.SYNC_HIGH_RES_PHOTO"
    context.startService(intent)
}
```

Before dispatching intent you can set observer, which will update your UI after synchronization is finished. Below you can find methods that will be useful in this case. Search respective docs for further details.

```
//For registering observer...
//uri - should be the same uri as uri calculated in dispatchSyncHighResPhotoIntent() function
//true - if should notify for descendants
//observer - your implementation of ContentObserver, which e.g. will update UI

context.contentResolver.registerContentObserver(uri, true, observer)


//For unregistering observer...
context.contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(observer)
```

After synchronization is finished, reading a contact's high-res photo should be done as in documentation, or e.g. by using Glide with URIs which are added in the Data table.

```
//Reading contact high-res photo as per Android documentation; true is for high-res photos
ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(contentResolver, contactUri, true)
```

Comment: Doesn't the `registerContentObserver` register for all changes and has a lot of false positives? How can you make it be filtered, to use it for just what you need, and only when it truly changes? Also I think the line with `intent.component` is not needed, because you can see Contacts app handle it without this part: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git/+/6d09f9313f7fa130aaca67cbafba74acb04fcca8%5E1..6d09f9313f7fa130aaca67cbafba74acb04fcca8/